# How to warm aws lambda using gatling

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I am write some test using gatling. I am issuing a request to an api gateway which calls a lambda function and gets the response. I am testing it with 50 concurrent users. I want to make some assertions against the mean response time but I get very varying values because of the lambda cold start problem.

This is my code:

```
override fun before() {
        println("warming up lambda")
        warmerRequest.injectOpen(atOnceUsers(10)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    }

    init {
        setUp(success.injectOpen(
            atOnceUsers(CONCURRENT_USERS)
        ).protocols(httpProtocol))
            .assertions(
                global().failedRequests().count().shouldBe(0L),
                global().responseTime().mean().lt(5000),
                global().successfulRequests().percent().shouldBe(100.0)
            )
```

I want to warm up my lambda before starting the simulation so that I can assert against mean response times otherwise I get very huge response times and the assertions fail. Is there any way to achieve this in Gatling using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Featured in Gatling Enterprise: https://gatling.io/docs/enterprise/cloud/reference/user/simulations/#step-4-time-window

Comment: is this not available via gatling plugin ?

Comment: No, only featured in the Enterprise version.